# Highlight chosen tab on toolbar

Tags: java, android, xml, toolbar, highlight

In my android project I have a toolbar that switches between 2 different pages/states (the toolbar is, of course, visible in both pages). The toolbar isn't really implemented as a real toolbar per se, but more like a set of buttons - when you click one of the buttons it takes you to that page (if you aren't there already).

Basically what I want to do is to make it so if I'm on tab #1 and press on tab #2 it highlights tab #2 and then switches to that page.

How would I implement this the easiest? I guess I could make the button 'lighter' on each of the pages but that feels like a sloppy solution.

**Left one selected**

[image: Left one selected]

**Right one selected**

[image: Right one selected]

Screen cap from Safari but I guess that's how I want it to look. I apologize in advance if the question doesn't make sense but I'm merely a beginner building android stuff.

Im using android studio w/ XML & Java if that is of any relevance. Any help greatly appreciated!

Edit: I was asked to provide some code of my implementations, here goes;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/bh_pastel_red"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/adViewBtn"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/system_txt_adView"
        android:textSize="@dimen/bh_button_font_size"
        android:background="@drawable/fragment_tab_settings_button"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxHeight="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="13dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/profileViewBtn"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/bh_button_font_size"
        android:text="@string/system_txt_profileView"
        android:background="@drawable/fragment_tab_settings_button"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxHeight="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="13dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

That is the fragment that I import in both of the page views.

Comment: can you provide some code of how you've implemented tabs?

Comment: Of course, I've included my code now!